# PostgreSQL 9.5 Coalesce

Tags: postgresql, coalesce, postgresql-9.5

I have a table "recipes" with columns named "name", "description", "preparation".
To enable Full-Text-Search i did:

```
ALTER TABLE recipes ADD COLUMN recipes_searchtext TSVECTOR;

CREATE INDEX idx_recipes_searchtext_gin ON recipes USING GIN(recipes_searchtext);
UPDATE recipes SET recipes_searchtext = 
setweight(to_tsvector('german',name), 'A') ||
setweight(to_tsvector('german',description), 'B') ||
setweight(to_tsvector('german',preparation), 'C');
```

I'm new to PostgreSQL, but as far as i can see after some testing this works fine for me.

But then i read about "COALESCE" to handle NULL Values.
So i tried:

```
UPDATE recipes SET recipes_searchtext = 
setweight(to_tsvector('german',COALESCE(name), 'A')) ||
setweight(to_tsvector('german',COALESCE(description), 'B')) ||
setweight(to_tsvector('german',COALESCE(preparation), 'C'));
```

what resulted in Error Message

> Funktion to_tsvector(unknown, character varying, unknown

Can someone please give me a hint what i'm doing wrong?

regards dirk

Comment: `COALESCE(name)` makes little sense. To be usefull, coalesce() needs more than one argument, in this case probably `COALESCE(name, '')`. [but I doubt if you need coalesce() at all, here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have the parentheses in the wrong place.

`to_tsvector` takes at most 2 arguments, but the way you have it right now it is taking three.

This should fix it:

```
UPDATE recipes SET recipes_searchtext = 
setweight(to_tsvector('german',COALESCE(name)), 'A') ||
setweight(to_tsvector('german',COALESCE(description)), 'B') ||
setweight(to_tsvector('german',COALESCE(preparation)), 'C');
```

However, I don't see a difference between your queries.  `coalesce` will return `null` if all its arguments are `null`.  You can provide a default value if you want like so:  `coalesce(name, 'Nothing')` which will return `'Nothing'` if `name` is `null`